# Extract text from textOutput() function

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Shiny's **textOutput()** returns HTML code. I need what's the text (or value) stored under textOutput() function. For example : textOutput('login_message') returns

```
<div id="login_message" class="shiny-text-output"></div>
```

Instead I need **TRUE / FALSE** (as shown in the code below).

````
```{r, context = 'server'}
output$login_message <- renderText({

current_user <- session$userData$current_user()$displayName
if(!is.null(current_user)) {TRUE} else {FALSE}

})
````

I tested the code and it works fine.

````
```{r}
textOutput('login_message')
````

I want TRUE/FALSE to be used in **eval =** so that I can hide chunk based on value from server part of shiny.

````
```{r q1, echo = FALSE, eval= textOutput('login_message') }
````

Note : I am using **shiny_prerendered** markdown